# Deploy error: List has no rows for assignment to SObject and INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY

Tags: error, package, null-pointer, destructivechanges.xml, deployment-error

I am trying to deploy a [destructive package](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/daas_destructive_changes.htm), but I am receiving the following errors in test classes:

- System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, OpportunityLineItemTriggers: execution of BeforeInsert caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
- System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 0067h00000BGr8vAAD; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, 0067h00000BGr8v: []
- System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
- System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject

P.s: these errors appeared in several test classes that were inserting and updating accounts, opportunities and users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the Sharing Calculation was disable.

So, using an Admin user:

- Enter in setup,
- in quick search, type "Defer Sharing Calculation" and select it.
- Then active it.
- Try to deploy your package again.